# How can I get a page number on the last page of a chapter with the mwrep class?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Text \pagebreak

Text \pagebreak

Text
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Text
\end{document}
```

This does not generate page number on last page within chapter. How can I change that?

Comment: From a reading of `mwrep.cls` it seems that it does it by design. But I'd consider this behavior a bug rather than good design.

Comment: @egreg: Nice interpretation ;-)

Comment: there is a message in the log from a job run from `mwrep` that clearly says "Beta version. Formatting may change in future versions of this class."  i suggest writing to the author, whose e-mail address is given in the readme file, viewable with `texdoc mwrep`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@closing\ps@plain
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Text \pagebreak

Text \pagebreak

Text
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Text
\end{document}
```